# How to configure OAuth2 with implicit flow with Swagger-UI in spring boot microservice application

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, swagger, jhipster, adfs

I have a spring boot microservice application created in jhipster with angular as frond-end. recently the authentication is changed to ADFS. I am using implicit grant flow to acquire the access token. But after that migration, the swagger UI is not working. I whitelisted the URI to get the API details so that we can view the API details. but to execute those APIs I need the actual access token.

I couldn't find much documentation on ADFS integration for swagger UI.

can anyone point me in the right direction for this integration?